# How can I require a minimum number of characters in a column with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]  DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [TestLevelId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [TestStatusId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [ExamId]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [Text]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sequence]     INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Release]      NVARCHAR (50)  DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Version]      ROWVERSION     NOT NULL,
    [Price]        MONEY          DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate]  DATETIME       NULL,
    [Code]         VARCHAR (10)   DEFAULT (LEFT(newid(), (5))) NOT NULL
);
```

I set the Code column to have a default but how can I also make it so the Code column has a value that is at least 5 characters?

Comment: create a check constraint: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Use a check constranint: `check (length(code) >= 5)`? (I'm not sure if `length()` exists in SQL Server, but some function with a similar name must be there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE AdminTest
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_AdminTest_Code_Length CHECK (LEN(Code) >= 5);
GO
```

Ref: [CHECK Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx)