# Is there a way I can create a constraint that checks the value of two columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]  DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [TestLevelId]  INT            NOT NULL,
    [TestStatusId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [ExamId]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [Text]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Sequence]     INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Release]      NVARCHAR (50)  DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [Version]      ROWVERSION     NOT NULL,
    [Price]        MONEY          DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate]  DATETIME       NULL,
    [Code]         VARCHAR (10)   DEFAULT (LEFT(newid(), (5))) NOT NULL
);
```

Is there a way that I can require the `ReleaseDate` to have a value IF the value of the `Release` column is 2 ?

Comment: check constraints in SQL SERVER

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201578/how-can-i-require-a-minimum-number-of-characters-in-a-column-with-sql-server

Comment: This might indicate that things aren't modelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

While ALTER:

```
ALTER TABLE AdminTest

ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Check CHECK (Release=2)  ;
```

While Creation

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN(
Release int
  CONSTRAINT DF_Check CHECK (Release=2) 
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define check constraint inline as a column constraint, like this -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Release]      NVARCHAR (50)  DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate]  DATETIME  NULL CONSTRAINT CK_Release CHECK (Release='2') ,
    [Code]         VARCHAR (10)   DEFAULT (LEFT(newid(), (5))) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Not if it references multiple columns.